# Entity Framework - unmapped entity. Possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to create an entity that is not mapped to a table in the database?

I created an entity (A) with 5 properties (name, phone, email, date, comment). There is no table named A in my database.

I queried the other tables in my model using linq and convert the result to a list of type (A)

```
IList<A> results = new IList<A>();
results = (from m in B
           where m.Id < 10
           select new { m.name, m.email, m.date, m.phone, m.comment }).ToList();
return View(results)
```

I did this to prevent from passing an anonymous type to my view.

Comment: Unmapped entity, what's the benefit? Why not just create a class then?

Comment: A class? It's Friday my brain is on the verge of shutting down. But why wouldn't an unmapped entity work?

Comment: Someone just told me that instead of creating an entity I could have created a Complex Type

Comment: My point is that if it isn't mapped to anything, why would you need entity framework for it? Seems like you just could create a class with those 5 properties. It's monday now so maybe it will make sense!
I think you might need to update and restructure your question with more details on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I need EF for the 5 other tables that are mapped.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are assigning something to variable `results` you don't need to create a new list. The following will work:

```
IList<A> results;       // No value yet.
```

Then you can instantiate `A` just like you would do otherwise.

```
results = (from m in B
          where m.Id < 10
          select new A(m.name, m.email, m.date, m.phone, m.comment))
          .ToList();

return View(results)
```

However, your assumption is wrong here. You say: *I convert the result to a list of type `A` to prevent from passing an anonymous type to my view*, but your idea of anonymous types is incorrect.

The following will *not* create an anonymous type. It will create a very unanonymous `IEnumerable<A>` or `IQueryable<A>`:

```
var results = from m in B
              select new A();
```

However, the following *will* create an anonymous type:

```
var results = from m in B
              select new {
                  Name = m.name,
                  Email = m.email,
                  Date = m.date,
                  Phone = m.phone,
                  Comment = m.comment
              };
```

Comment: I think you could use automapper to do this.